# (401) Unauthorized with python-firebase

Tags: python, authentication, firebase

I am trying to update Firebase using the [python-firebase](https://github.com/ozgur/python-firebase) library, but cannot get authentication to work, using adapted sample code:

```
from firebase import firebase as fb
auth = fb.FirebaseAuthentication('<firebase secret>', 'me@gmail.com', 
                                 auth_payload={'uid': '<uid>'}) // NB renamed extras -> auth_payload, id -> uid here
firebase = fb.FirebaseApplication('https://<url>.firebaseio.com', authentication=auth)
result = firebase.get('/users', name=None, connection=None, 
                      params={'print': 'pretty'}) // HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized
print result
```

I keep getting (401) Unauthorized, but I notice that the token generated by the library is radically different to one generated by a [JavaScript version of FirebaseTokenGenerator](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/D4YL8/light/) - and the latter authenticates fine when I provide the same URL, uid and secret.

I noticed a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/ozgur/python-firebase/issues/30), questioning why the library did not just use the [official Python firebase-token-generator](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-token-generator-python), so I [forked](https://github.com/moconnell/python-firebase/tree/use-firebase-token-generator) and implemented the suggested change just in case it would make a difference, but still get the same result.

Can anyone suggest what might be tripping me up here?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `python-firebase` client (it's not officially supported by Firebase), but I can help you verify whether or not the JWT you are generating is valid. Type your JWT into http://jwt.io/ and make sure the payload is as you would expect. It should contain the uid you intended. Also, type in your secret and make sure the signature is verified. If not, then the token being generated is invalid. Knowing that info will help us debug this. Also, double check that you are using the correct secret.

Comment: signature: verified, according to jwt.io

Comment: actually, I think it may be as simple as using the correct secret. I just tried to get "/messages" i/o "/users" and it worked. Seems like the default secret does not have access to the "/users" node. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed?  I get that auth_payload is an unexpected argument in that call.

Comment: The key is in the comment, most likely - 
`// NB renamed extras -> auth_payload, id -> uid here` - assuming you are using standard python-firebase, try renaming `auth_payload` to `extras`

Answer (score 0):

This library is 4 years old which means lots of things have been changed for firebase especially after Google's acquisition. The part of how you access Firebase is completely different.

I will recommend to use the official Firebase Admin Python SDK https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python

A really good alternative but prefer the official is this:

https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase

Comment: These libreries don't have support for Python 2.7, so `python-firebase-gae` is the best when I have worked with Python 2.7